# Java; Writing int from characters in file to an array

Tags: java, filereader

I need to convert a file into an int array, my source have a strict formatting. Each single character correspond a int(or byte) to be stored in an array, spacing delimiting a new array in a 2D Array.

The file would be formatted as so. (x,y,z coordinates), each character of a 3 number string needing to be stored individually.

```
013 234 456 567
```

My desired output would be as so.

```
{0,1,3}{2,3,4}{4,5,6}{5,6,7}
```

Would there be achieve directly from a file reading method or will I have to import them as string with a scanner, than separate the numbers from there?

Comment: You must write code to do this. But it can be done in 1 line.

Comment: Because we're programmers: what does `101213 242526 858584` turn into? Because there is no reason for that to be `{10,12,13}...`, it could just as easily be `{1012,1,3}`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added some clarification, each character is it's own number. Which is kinda my problem, as to not read the them as (int 123) but {1,2,3}.

Comment: In that case, just read the entire string, split it into an array of single letters, and then iterate over that. If you see a space, you know you need to move on to the next tuple, if it's not, convert to int and do what you need to do with that, given a knowledge of "how many numbers you already saw". You should be able to least write _some_ code yourself here that you can add into your post.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's pretty much what I was asking, If I could do it another way. But if not, seems fine I'll do it that way then. :) Import as strings, separate characters and convert into integers. Just felt a bit roundabout, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[][][] array = Files.lines(Path.of("myfilename.txt"))
    .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")) // split line into terms
            .map(term -> term.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray()) // convert each term to int[]
            .toArray(int[][]::new)) // convert each line to int[][]
    .toArray(int[][][]::new); // convert all lines of file to a single int[][][]
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/sQwbEA).

Comment: I ended up using another solution, due to other limitations, but this was an interesting way to do things. I'll keep that in mind.